# Maintain the current count of buildings in a different table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, aggregate-functions, sql-view

I have two tables:

Table `apartments`:

| house_no | house_street |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pomona |
| 2 | Pomona |
| 1 | Dubai |
| 2 | Dubai |

Table `streets`:

| street_name | total_buildings |
| --- | --- |
| Dubai | *NULL* |
| Pomona | *NULL* |

I would love the column `streets.total_buildings` to be occupied by the `COUNT` of the total `house_no` values under each unique `house_street` (Dubai, Pomona,...) in table `apartments`.

`streets.street_name` should represent the `house_street` column in table `apartments` and `streets.total_buidlings` should be updated automatically upon every entry in table apartments.

I tried the code to extract the count of the number of house_no values under a house_street in table apartments:

```
SELECT count(house_street), house_street
FROM apartments
GROUP BY house_street
```

I got the result:

| count | house_street |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Pomona |
| 2 | Dubai |

But this does not fully solve the problem?

Comment: if you could post the tables as text (even better: provide a fiddle) it would be great.

Comment: Why store the same information in two different tables? To me, someone that has been working with databases for many many years, this is a recipe for disaster. If you want the count, then just run your SELECT statement. You can create a `view` in postgres for that SQL so you can just `SELECT * FROM street_house_count_view;` so you don't have to remember how to write that logic, if that is a concern.

Comment: @JNevill well said. But the two tables do not contain the same information. Check through again, you'll realise the table apartments lists house streets with different house numbers i.e a house street can have house_no values of up to 40  but table streets contains a summary of these house_street values including their count, and more columns like no of rooms, structure (duplex, bungalow) can be added. These are best stored in a separate table to minimise duplicates in table apartments.

Comment: Why store aggregates of one table in another table? That is data duplication. Anytime you are thinking "When data changes in Table A, I need to automatically update Table B" then you are almost always heading in the wrong direction. If you can get the results you want with basic SQL and the response is fast where materialization is not needed, then there is no reason to consider materialization as a solution. If your SQL is more complex and you are running it often, then sling it into a view.

Comment: Noted. Considering materialisation has been the issue. A view has worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the table `streets` with a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html):

```sql
CREATE VIEW streets AS
SELECT house_street AS street_name, count(house_no) AS total_buildings
FROM   apartments
GROUP  BY 1;
```

It's in the nature of a view that it's always up to date.

If `house_no` is defined `NOT NULL` (or maybe in any case if you want to count those null values, too) you can replace `count(house_no)` with `count(*)`.

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. Although I grouped by house_street.

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` is just short syntax for `GROUP BY house_street`. You know that, right?